# Read multiple text files

Tags: r, text

I am reading the attached .txt file using the R code below. I have 2200 txt files like this with different station IDs. I need to output only the year for peak flow data available. For example,

```
Year     Peak 
1929   4050 
1940   7000 
1958   4050 
...
```

Can somebody help me to modify this code to achive this.

My R code is shown below.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) 
iPath <- 'C:/Desktop/flow_raw/Region-03/' 
mydata <- read.table("02053200-PeakFlow-uptoWY2015.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE) 
out <- mydata[c(3,5)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read all files in one directory into R at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382880/how-to-read-all-files-in-one-directory-into-r-at-once)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758084/loop-in-r-loading-files

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see any attached file.

There are various options to accomplish the task.

```
library(plyr)   #you only need these packages if you follow my first Option
library(dplyr)

files <- dir("C:/Desktop/flow_raw/Region-03", 
             full.names = TRUE)


# OPT. 1: if you need a Data Frame
df <- lapply(files, function(x) 
      read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE)[c(3,5)]) %>% 
      plyr::ldply()    #the '.id' argument might be useful

# OPT. 2: if you need a list
listTxt <- lapply(files, function(x) 
           read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE)[c(3,5)])
```

NB: If you need a FAST reading function, please, take a look at

> data.table::fread

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I try to install the "plyr" packages mentioned above in RStudio, I get the following error message.    install.packages("plyr")
also installing the dependency ‘Rcpp’

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcpp’ ‘plyr’
  These will not be installed                Can somebody help me to figure this out? Thanks

Comment: You need to install "Rcpp" first (and in general it is a good idea because Rcpp is now used by more than 500 R packages). If you are not able to install "Rcpp", please, paste the output of `sessionInfo()` here, I will try to help you.

Comment: I tried installing Rcpp. But I cannot install. Here is the message I got.  install.packages("Rcpp")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcpp’
  These will not be installed.

Comment: that's why I've asked you to paste your `sessionInfo()` here :)

Comment: NB: different system configurations require different installation steps

Comment: I was able to install all the packpages but when I view "df" it has all the records catenated. How can I sort flow record for each station? For example I need to output a csv file name as the station ID and flow records in the csv file.

Comment: 1. I will all the group by type of operations using dplyr; e.g., `sortedDf <- df %>% group_by(StationID) %>% arrange(desc(Peak))` and then 2. write the files out splitting by station ID `lapply(split(sortedDf, sortedDf$StationID), function(y) write.csv(x = y[c(1,3)], file = paste0(y$StationID[1], '.csv')))`

Comment: p.s. You did not give us your 'dput' output, so for the examples I am assuming this one `dput(df)` dput(df)
structure(list(Year = c(1929, 1929, 1929, 1929, 1929, 1930, 1931, 
1934), StationID = c("WTF2", "WTF2", "WTF2", "WTF3", "WTF3", 
"WTF3", "YAAI", "YAAI"), Peak = c(500, 4050, 6000, 8000, 7623, 
2134, 4578, 6348), .id = c("file1", "file1", "file1", "file2", 
"file2", "file2", "file3", "file3")), .Names = c("Year", "StationID", 
"Peak", ".id"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: Please see the images above of the 'df' output and text file which is reading by the code. As you can see it does not read the station ID (in the above image 02053200). How can I modify the R code to read station ID, year, and flow (i.e 2nd column, 3rd column (year) and 4th column).

Comment: Hi, I use for my example those columns because that's what your gave us in your example code, if you need the 2nd, the 3rd, and the 4th just edit the reading function as `read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE)[2:4])`

Comment: Hi, I made the changes but still it does not read all three columns. Please see the image above. It only reads column 2 but not column 3 and 4.

Comment: Based only on the 4 lines of data that I can see from your screenshot, the following should be work for you `read.table(x, sep = '\t', header = FALSE, skip = 2)[2:4])`.

Comment: could please you just attach one real file?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to import 2200 text files at once. For some reason I can't see the attachment, but you should be able to read in the data using the function Corpus from the tm package.

In your case: (the path should lead to a folder where all the text files live)

```
TextCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Desktop/flow_raw/Region-03"))
TextCorpus$content
```

You should be able to subset these documents. I usually make a list of the documents' content so that you would have a list of 2200 elements containing the original text.

Comment: I get the following error message, > install.packages("tm")
also installing the dependency ‘slam’

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘slam’ ‘tm’
  These will not be installed